# What are the prerequisites to study CP violation?

Tags: particle-physics, soft-question, standard-model, cp-violation

If one would like to study [CP violation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP_violation), what would be the prerequisites for it?

For example, until now I have not studied quantum field theory and have done very little classical field theory, but I have done some quantum mechanics—non-relativistic and relativistic. What else do I need?

Comment: Do you mean what are the prerequisite conditions for CP violation to happen, or what are the academic subjects you need to study to understand CP violation?

Comment: And to add to David's question, do you intend to understand the topic on a theoretical level or what it takes to demonstrate CP violation in an experiment (a complicated topic in itself but requiring a bit less math and rather a lot more understanding of the limits of detector kit)?

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: I need to know the academic subjects needed to understand CP violation.
to dmckee: Both. But as a priority I want to understand it on a theoretical level.
Thanks.